# Can I download previous versions of single apps without re-downloading the entire OS?

Tags: preview, highlights

Is there a way of just downloading specific apps from previous versions of macOS? Specifically, I want to download the El Capitan version of Preview or revert back to it. The colors on Sierra are way too dark it makes it harder to read the text for some of them.

Comment: Nope, but you can get a different PDF viewer application.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a question about fixing your issue with colours, rather than trying to change the version of Preview. Especially since it's likely the issue would remain with the older version of Preview because you'd still be running it in macOS Sierra.